# How to use a for loop with input function

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, user-input

I simply have to make a sum of three numbers and calculate the average

```
import sys
sums=0.0
k=3
for w in range(k):
    sums = sums + input("Pleas input number " + str(w+1) + " ")
print("the media is " + str(sums/k) + " and the Sum is " + str(sums))
```

And the error :

```
Pleas input number 1 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Python/sec001.py", line 5, in <module>
    sums = sums + input("Pleas input number " + str(w+1) + " ");
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Think of the type of the value returned by `input(..)` by trying `type(input("> "))` in your console; you'll see it is of type `str`. Can a `str` be added to a float (`sums`) without first being converted?

Comment: Yep, just needed to cast an INT

Comment: `SemicolonOverflow Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` function returns a string(str) and Python does not convert it to float/integer automatically. All you need to do is to convert it.

```
import sys;
sums=0.0;
k=3;
for w in range(k):
    sums = sums + float(input("Pleas input number " + str(w+1) + " "));
print("the media is " + str(sums/k) + " and the Sum is " + str(sums));
```

If you want to make it even better, you can use try/except to deal with invalid inputs. Also, `import sys` is not needed and you should avoid using semicolon.

```
sums=0.0
k=3
for w in range(k):
    try:
        sums = sums + float(input("Pleas input number " + str(w+1) + " "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
print("the media is " + str(sums/k) + " and the Sum is " + str(sums))
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not do the simple version then optimize it?

```
def sum_list(l):
    sum = 0
    for x in l:
        sum += x
    return sum

l = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers separated by spaces:  ").split())) 
sum_list(l)
```

Your problem was that you were not casting your input from 'str' to 'int'. Remember, Python auto-initializes data types. Therefore, explicit casting is required. Correct me if I am wrong, but that's how I see it.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Why not optimize your code to use Python's built in sum function?

Comment: You are correct! Beg my pardon, but why have you edited the parameter list to 'l' instead of 'n'. If 'l' is to be used then all changes must be made.

Comment: My bad I have made a mistake :)

Comment: Your loop has `for x in l`. I fixed it

Comment: Thank you. Silly mistakes kill me :\

Comment: The parameter name needs not match the variable. My edit worked. Yours was meaningless

Comment: True as well but for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string and you need to create an `int` or `float` from that. You also have to deal with the fact that users can't follow simple instructions. Finally, you need to get rid of those semicolons - they are dangerous and create a hostile work environment (at least when you bump into other python programmers...!)

```
import sys
sums=0.0
k=3
for w in range(k):
    while True:
        try:
            sums += float(input("Pleas input number " + str(w+1) + " "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("That was not a number")
print("the media is " + str(sums/k) + " and the Sum is " + str(sums))
```